# No result sonar qube in Xcode

Tags: xcode, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed SonarQube successfully and executed command `$sonar-runner` on sample project provided in sonar-examples-master folder. But when I am trying to see report on browser it shows me everything 0 and  The project has passed the quality gate. in the status.

I tried with my project also. Can anybody help me? Is there anything I am missing with?

[image: SonarQubeStatusPage]

Comment: Did you install the plugins related to the languages you want to analyse? By default you get only java files analysed.

Answer (score 0):

You also appear to have 0 lines of code. Double-check your configuration and make sure you properly specified `sonar.sources`. Your analysis log should also give you some hints about how many source files were found during analysis.